# Building the game making two launcher icon of game in unity 3d for android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am working on the Unity3D and its my first time on it, I was editing some code and that's gone fine , I know and read how to build the game and make the release `apk` and I did. But there is a problem which is as Under.

**Problem :**

> When ever I install the game from Apk or directly from the Unity3D ,
>   both gives me 2 launcher icon. And those two launcher icon are able to run the game as expected.  But I am not able to understand why there is two launcher icon.

**What I want:**

> Well being as an android developer I know that there should be only
>   one launcher icon  of game, But there are two . I want that there
>   should be one launcher Icon

**Any idea why is it happening and what is a solution of it. ? Please help me as I am stuck in this problem.**

Comment: Is the problem that, when installing twice via 2 different methods there are 2 icons? Or that there are 4 icons total? - Because if the first, the solution is "Don't do that, you are installing two apps so you get 2 icons"

Comment: there are 2 luanching  icons , for building I just pressing ctrl + b  to build

Comment: if a single apk is installed twice on your device probably it's a matter of adb. try deleting and re-installing your Android sdk, or at least the adb and all the related components.

Comment: I have deleted app , made the apk , and installing the game via apk , but results are same. Even I have changed the device but still the same

Comment: what device do you have? is this problem occurs in any other device?

Comment: yeah I am using different devices and problem is there in all

Comment: can you tell me where I can find which xml is used and where xml I can found in the unity 3d

Comment: @MasihAkbari please reply

Comment: @CoasMckey check your `AndroidManifest.xml` file in you project folder

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I have followed the path to android plugin  which is located inside the plugin folder. there I found the manifest file

I opened that manifest file and found that there are 2 activities with the name of property of LAUNCHER. which is meant to launch first among all of other activities.

So I set that intent category to DEFAULT and then I built the game again . And thus I found only one Launcher icon of game.

This solved my problem. Posting this as answer because I thought some one might fall in this same situation so in this case he may found this as a useful answer.